# Pascals triangle pathways

Tags: optimization, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinations

[image]

Hey Guys I really really need help with my data management problem. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what to do. It deals with pascals triangle. The pegboard game is shown above. I really need help I genuinely do not know how to find the amount of paths, and because of that I can't move on. The questions is..

> Determine the total number of paths to the bottom of the game board (for each path). Include a separate game board for each starting slot (A-H)

Comment: Determine the number ways to reach the gray squares on each row in succession.

Comment: Incidentally do the numbers at the bottom of the board mean anything?

Answer (score -1):

If the numbers at the bottom don't mean anything and you just want the number of paths downward through the dotted squares, it is just like Pascal's triangle.  Starting from where you indicate there is one way to the neighboring cells on the top line and zero ways to all the other cells.  Now fill in the second line with each cell getting the sum of the two above.  It will exactly follow Pascal's triangle until the edges start to matter, when the numbers will be smaller.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: The numbers at the bottom do mean something, since its a gameboard I guess its the amount of points? And then there are 8 pathways

Comment: I have suggested how to find the number of paths from a given entry to each slot in the bottom. I thought that was your question. If it isn't, what is it?

Comment: So when I am done filling in the numbers from the start to end, how to I find out how many pathways per letter (like A,B, etc)?

Comment: You add up all the numbers at the bottom.  It would be $2^{12}$ per letter if you didn't lose the pathways at the edges because there are $12$ layers and you would have two choices at each layer.

Comment: So the amount of pathways for each letter is the same?

Comment: No, the letters in the middle will have more pathways.  The edge ones will lose more to the sides than the middle.  Have you just tried filling in the grid?

Comment: I filled in the whole grid. So basically you're saying that for the A row I add up all the numbers going down? For A I got 1, whereas for H I got 370.

Comment: No, the number at the bottom is the number of pathways from your entry to that cell in the bottom, so the total number of pathways from a starting point is the sum of all the cells at the bottom.  Starting at the point shown, I get $319$ in the leftmost cell at the bottom, $461$ in the next, and so on for a sum of $1914$.  I made a spreadsheet to do the computation.  The fourth row is $1,4,6,4,1,0,0,0$ just like Pascal's triangle.  Now we start to feel the left edge and the numbers are smaller than Pascal's

Comment: May I ask how you ended with 319 etc? I got 319 in the second last one but I still had to add up one more and I ended with 429

Comment: I had the window shifted and didn't see the leftmost column.  I assumed the numbers went in the gray squares.  The gray squares in the left column go $0,0,1,6,27,110$ which are the same as the squares up and to their right.  The column below the entry is $1,2,6,20,70,252$ which are alternate rows from Pascal's triangle.  This column hasn't felt the edge yet.

Comment: Do you think you could help me out with some of the other questions? Once I get one i'll get the hang out it!

Comment: Determine the probability of obtaining 0 points for each starting path.
Determine the probability of obtaining 5000 points for each starting path. For these questions what am I dividing what by?

Comment: The probability of getting 5000 points is the number just above 5000 divided by the sum of all the numbers in the bottom row on the assumption that all paths are equally likely.  That number counts the number of paths that end there.

Comment: So for my pathway A the number above 5000 is 54, this means that all the other numbers in the very last row in the grey boxes should be added up to divide with 54? Also when adding up all the bottom row numbers should I also add 54 too?

Comment: I would suggest you make a much smaller grid, say 3 by 3 or 4 by 4 and count the paths by hand from one entry.  That would help you understand what the numbers at the bottom mean.  I was trying to explain that with the last comment.